# JTable updates not appearing

Tags: java, user-interface, swing, jtable

I have a `JTable` with a custom `TableModel` called `DataTableModel`. I initialized the table with a set of column names and no data as follows:

```
books = new JTable(new DataTableModel(new Vector<Vector<String>>(), title2));
JScrollPane scroll1 = new JScrollPane(books);
scroll1.setEnabled(true);
scroll1.setVisible(true);
JSplitPane jsp1 = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.VERTICAL_SPLIT, scroll1, scroll2);
JSplitPane jsp2 = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.HORIZONTAL_SPLIT, inventory, jsp1);
myPanel.add(jsp2, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

I later want to update books with a set of data, and use the following:

```
DataTableModel d = (DataTableModel)books.getModel();
d.setValues(bookList);
books.setModel(d);
```

where bookList is a `Vector<Vector<String>>` that definitely has data. However, although all this code is being executed, it is not displaying on the screen. The code for the `setValues()` method is:

```
public void setValues(Vector<Vector<String>> v) {
    values = v;
    fireTableDataChanged();
}
```

Am I missing something here?

The class and methods for my DataTableModel are (these methods are all implemented to return correct results):

```
public class DataTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {
    public DataTableModel(Vector<Vector<String>> v, Vector<String> c) {}

    public int getColumnCount() {
        if (values != null && values.size() > 0)
            return values.elementAt(0).size();
        else
            return 0;
    }

    public int getRowCount() {
        if (values != null && values.size() > 0)
            return values.size();
        else
            return 0;
    }

    public Object getValueAt(int arg0, int arg1) {}
    public void setValues(Vector<Vector<String>> v) {}
    public Vector<Vector<String>> getValues() {}
    public void setColumnNames(Vector<String> columns) {}
    public String getColumnName(int col) {}
}
```

Comment: mhhh nope.. I think your model and your table are not connected. Can you post your actual code.. ?

Comment: Set model should be enough. . Did you code that DataTableModel your self?

Comment: Yes I did. And when I examine the DataTableModel, it seems to have the correct data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you implemented the other methods for `TableModel`? If so, how does your implementation look? Maybe you should post your table model code to let us inspect it?

BTW: My main error when implementing `TableModel` was to override `getRowCount()` and `getColumnCount()` to `return 0`. This will tell the table that there is no data to display...

EDIT: So you seem to be using something like an `AbstractTableModel` or a `DefaultTableModel`, right? Have you overridden some of the methods?

EDIT 2: You should call `fireTableStructureChanged` instead of `fireTabeDataChanged()`, because initially your table model is returning `0` for `getColumnCount()`.

EDIT 3: To further optimize your model you should consider returning a fixed value for `getColumnCount()` if you have data that has the same number of columns every time. Then you can call the `fireTabeDataChanged()` which just loads the new data instead of completely building up the table and data (`fireTableStructureChanged()`) every time.

Answer (score 0):

This is weird problem. You said that `DataTableModel` implements `TableModel`. So. If you does not use abstract class the problem should be in the way how you are handling the events. Are listeners really registered and then notified? If you can, please send link to source of `DataTableModel`. But before, verify that you are correctly handling listeners registered into this model.

Comment: I've debugged the code. The update code is really being called, as is the updateValues() method. So the fireTableDataChanged() method is also being called, with no errors, but the display is not changing.

Answer (score -1):

this solve the problem ; you not allowed to unbind the main  bindingGroup but you specify the jtablebinding to update it like this

```
Binding b = bindingGroup.getBindings().get(0);
b.unbind();
b.bind();
```